# Adding background on object

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong. I am using this code

```html
<div style="background-image: url('http://www.ionianradio.gr/radio1/images/tv5.png');" 
     align="center">
    <object id="livestreamPlayer" style="visibility: visible;"   
      data="http://cdn.livestream.com/chromelessPlayer/v20/playerapi.swf?channel=ionianradio&amp;color=0x000000&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;mute=false&amp;iconColorOver=0xe7e7e7&amp;iconColor=0xcccccc" 
      type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="950" height="500">
    </object>
    <div>
```

Unfortunatelly I am seeing only the object and not the background. I am not so sure if I can do this, though. Background is a tv monitor and the object is a livestream show.

Comment: It is working... just you need to add height and width--> try adding:

  height: 600px
  width: 1000px
Also u're div is not closed </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify `height` in `div` in order to the background show up.

snippet below:

```css
div {
  background-image: url('http://www.ionianradio.gr/radio1/images/tv5.png');
  height: 600px /*whatever you like*/
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <object id="livestreamPlayer" style="visibility: visible;" data="http://cdn.livestream.com/chromelessPlayer/v20/playerapi.swf?channel=ionianradio&amp;color=0x000000&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;mute=false&amp;iconColorOver=0xe7e7e7&amp;iconColor=0xcccccc" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  width="950" height="500"></object>
</div>
```

Notes:

- Try not to use inline CSS, since it is [not a good practice](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm), instead use `classes` or `ID's`
- You are using `align=center`, try to avoid that since it is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2), instead you can assign a `class`/`ID` and with CSS make it aligned center to what you need/want.

Comment: One more help, please. How am I putting a name in the div? Should I write: <div class="name"><div align="center">....and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your closing div tag is missing the slash. You may also need to add some additional styles to ensure the div is larger than the video player

```html
<div style="background-image: url('http://www.ionianradio.gr/radio1/images/tv5.png');" align="center"><object id="livestreamPlayer" style="visibility: visible;" data="http://cdn.livestream.com/chromelessPlayer/v20/playerapi.swf?channel=ionianradio&amp;color=0x000000&amp;autoPlay=false&amp;mute=false&amp;iconColorOver=0xe7e7e7&amp;iconColor=0xcccccc" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="950" height="500"></object>
</div>
```